# tsql conditions vs c# conditions performance

Tags: c#, performance, t-sql, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to know what performs faster and its preferable a condition in a tsql query like this:

`select case 'color' when 'red' then 1  when 'blue' then 2 else 3 end`

or performing the same switch in c# code after getting the value from the db?

```
switch(color):
{
   case "red":
      return 1;
   case "blue":
      return 2;
   default:
      return 3;
}
```

To add more data in my specific case we have a sql query that returns 5800+ records in some cases (date filters and so) then we concatenate those results in c# (one txt line per record) and generate a txt.

We have one server that is the sql server + webserver(asp.net) and it takes like 10 or more mins to generate it...So we where thinking about doing all the conditions on the sql side, maybe concatenating the fields as one at the sql level too vs using c# loop with StringBuilder?

Right now the sql takes 1 sec to execute and all the time its taken at the concatening loop, there are 5873 records with 11 fields each

Comment: Too many different variables to really answer this. Are they running on the same machine? What are you doing that requires this level of fine tuning?

Comment: The `performance` tag wiki has some tips on submitting questions, in particular that you should bring some measurements.  Consider how you would go about measuring this.

Comment: Is your goal to write a text file from a SQL query?  Exporting CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are prematurely optimizing. "Make it work, make it right, then make it fast."

I know this statement (and others like it) bring about a lot of debate, but I think you should be putting this logic in the layer that is most appropriate, as in, where it has the least duplication, most re-usability, easiest to maintain, etc. If you have a performance problem at that point, you can make actual measurements in your environment with your own loads.

As an example, rather than some naked switch like this (that must be maintained), perhaps this should be in a lookup table in the DB and brought back with a join, or maybe it's better exposed as a property of some class based upon an enum.  These might be better patterns to follow.

Comment: the logic its already implemented and in production, the problem now is the performance...

Comment: in the end you were right, i missed the step "make it right", using a try/catch in an external function made the loop extremely slow as it entered the catch too often...changing the try/catch to  if(stringx.lenght>numx) solved the problem... thanks

Comment: Strictly speaking, Kent Beck was right.  I'm glad you were able find and remove the catch from actual control flow.

Answer (score 0):

All things being equal on processors, your performance is probably going to depend more on workload and bandwidth.

Will you be saving any bandwidth by replacing the string with an integer or simply adding an integer column?  Will there be any filtering on rows which result in significantly less data going across the wire?

If you have 2 web servers and 1 sql server, the processor work will be divided by doing it on the web server.  If you have thousands of rich clients and 1 sql server, the processor work will be completely distributed by doing it on the clients.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really possible to say, as there are too many unknown factors.

It depends for example on how much data you return from the database, how you handle the data returned, and whether the database server or the application server is at capacity.

The `switch` in itself would be faster than the `select`, but that could easily be outweighed by the fact that returning a number instead of a string from the database could be faster to handle in the code.

Comment: @ase69s: If it takes 10 minutes to concatenate 64000 strings, then you are doing something seriously wrong. I would expect it to take a few seconds at most. Shaving a few milliseconds off by doing conversions in the database won't change much, you have to find out what it is that is taking time in your implementation.

Comment: I agree with @Guffa. This sounds like you're selecting from the DB thousands of times and/or opening a text file thousands of times.